# jQuery: how to find a specific class if you don't know, where it is or what parent it has

Tags: jquery

I'm used to work with techniques like `$(this).parent().next().find('.class').doThings();` and it's working quite well. Now I'm facing the issue, that I'm looking for an element that gets generated in a table - but not in an fixed column or row (so it can be in the first column, in the last or anywhere in between)

The input field I'm looking for has an generated ID

I know the ID of the actual table furthermore the element i'm looking for is always within the same table row as `$(this)` refers to. Is there any way I'm able to use my `doThings()` class on an for me unknown element?

the table I'm working with is somewhat like this:

`this` -> the button that triggers and starts my jquery

`elpos{1-4}` -> all possible positions of the element

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
+ thead  | thead  | thead  | thead  | thead  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
+ elpos1 | elpos2 | elpos3 | elpos4 | this   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Do you know the name of the class you want to find? if so then why cant you use `$("#tableID").find(".className")`

Comment: I don't understand the question. It sounds like you want to call a function on an element for which you don't know the class, id, position or any other identifiable features.

Comment: Now, when I read the question for a second time, it does sounds like so actually @Moob. OP please clarify the question - what do you know about the element you are looking for?

Comment: sorry, guys for the confusion. I know the class of the element i'm looking for, but it can be in other `<tr>` as well, with `$('#table').find('.class');` I'm finding every element with the specific class, even tho I just need those within the `<tr>`. If I try to use `$('tr').find('.class');` instead it finds again all .class elements within the entire table

Answer (score 1):

Just don't look relatively. If you know that element you are looking for is in the table `#table` then use the ID as the root element to start searching:

```
$('#table').find('.class');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve but this demo shows how you can use jQuery to find a specific element within the same row of the button which was clicked. Hopefully this will give you enough to go on.

```js
$("#myTable").on("click","button",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $button = $(this);
  $button.parents("tr").find(".me").css("color","red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<th>col1</th>
<th>col2</th>
<th>col3</th>
<th>col4</th>
<th>col5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="me">elem</span></td>
<td><span>elem</span></td>
<td><span>elem</span></td>
<td><span>elem</span></td>
<td><button>button</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>elem</span></td>
<td><span>elem</span></td>
<td><span>elem</span></td>
<td><span class="me">elem</span></td>
<td><button>button</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>elem</span></td>
<td><span>elem</span></td>
<td><span class="me">elem</span></td>
<td><span>elem</span></td>
<td><button>button</button></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

```
var element = $(this)
  .parent() //td
  .parent() //tr
  .find('.my-class');
```